# How to generate key for git on NAS server?

Tags: ssh, git, nas

I'm trying to set up git on my NAS server (Synology DS212J), and now I've gotten to the part where you're supposed to copy my public key... but I don't really understand what it is referring to.

Is there some way to generate this key for a NAS?

I'm following these instructions:
http://www.wonko.de/2010/04/set-up-git-on-synology-nas.html

And got to this step:

```
Now copy your public key to a share and move it to the authorized_keys file:
mkdir -p /volume1/home/user1/.ssh
mv /volume1/someshare/id_dsa.pub /volume1/home/user1/.ssh/authorized_
```

But when I tried typing those lines in, I got:

> nas> mv /volume1/_git/id_dsa.pub /volume1/home/user1/.ssh/authorized
>   mv: can't rename '/volume1/_git/id_dsa.pub': No such file or directory

I had created a new shared directory called "_git" in the NAS.

Comment: Some troubleshooting questions: What is the result of: `cd /volume1; ls -al; cd _git; ls -al`? Did you ever run the `ssh-keygen` command? Do you know if you already have a public/private key?  You can place all your answers as edits to your question (easier to read ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

then copy the public part of the key to the auth file on the server.